# drawing triangle in c

Tags: c, loops

I'm currently working on an exercise to draw a triangle from a C program. The user inputs the height of the triangle in the command line and the triangle is printed with "*"s.

For example, an input of 3 will output:

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    //initialize height variable and bottom variable
    int height, limit;
    //take command line argument and save it as an int. This ensures
    height = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("You have chosen to draw a triangle of height: %d\n", height);

    if (height<1) {
        printf("ERROR: Height too small.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (height>100) {
        printf("ERROR: Height too large.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
    {
            limit=0;

        // this 'for' loop will take care of printing the blank spaces
        for (int j = 1; j <= height; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        //This while loop actually prints the "*"s of the triangle.
        while(limit!=2*i-1) {
            printf("*");
            limit++;
        }
        limit=0;
        //We print a new line and start the loop again
        printf("\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

I have two problems:

1. The triangle produced by the program has the correct number of *'s, and is offset the correct number of spaces, but only produces a half triangle.

This is the current output of my program:

```
  *
  ***
  *****
```

2. I'm not sure how to form the if statement to catch if the user enters something that is not an integer. Using atoi() casts the input as an integer, but if the user enters, say, "yes", the error that the height is too small will be thrown. How can I work around this?

Comment: Just a note, before that, if i only run the executable, i'll get a segfault. :)

Comment: Segfault means 'bug'.  You need to print fewer spaces at the front of the line on the second and third lines than on the first; you need to modify your loop to accommodate that.  Using `atoi()` means you won't get useful error reporting (but you will report 'infinity' as 'too small').  Consider using `strtol()` — but look for questions on SO on how to do so because it is hard to use well. Or consider GIGO: Garbage In, Garbage Out. A bad input yields an error message, but not a good one. Print error messages on standard error (`stderr`); that's what it's for. And print the erroneous value too.

Comment: Just a note, you should check `argc` (number of arguments) before de-referencing `argv` which is what causes your segfault when running the executable with no arguments.

Comment: ummm, I don't understand why everyone is replying to my comment. It was a hypothetical one. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's cause for some reason I thought the use of the "I" pro-noun meant you were the OP.  Didn't check the names.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: me too...

Comment: your blank space loop has no variability.  With any height H, it will print H spaces every line, every time.

Comment: Well this is a lot of information at once. Should my if statement look like
 `if (argc==NULL) 
{printf("error")}`

Comment: OK, I was just trying to pass a hint to OP. It's ok, I believe OP got the required info. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop that prints leading spaces is always printing the same amount of spaces each time.  You need to print 1 less space on each subsequent line.  You can do this by starting the loop with `j=i` instead of `j=1`.

Instead of using `atoi()`, use `strtol()` as follows:

```
char *p;
errno = 0 ;
height = strtol(argv[1], &p, 10);
if (errno != 0 || p == argv[1]) {
    printf("invalid input");
    exit(1);
}
```

If there's an error in parsing, `errno` will be set to a non-zero value.  The `p` parameter on return will point to the first character that is not a digit.  So if it points to the start of the string, then it's not a number.

Also, be sure to check that `argv[1]` is actually present:

```
if (argc < 2) {
    printf("not enough arguments\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the '10' in your `strtol` statement?

Comment: @KommanderKitten That specifies that the number is in base 10.  You could pass in 2 for binary, 8 or octal, 16 for hexidecimal, or any base from 2 to 36.

Answer (score 0):

I've found, though not necessary, it is always better to give your ints an initial value. Can cause very annoying bugs when the program gets bigger. Also define your i and j at the beginning.

```
int height = 0;
int limit = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

Also j should be a different value each time. For example:

```
for(j = i; j <= height; j++)
{
  printf(" ");
}
```

As for the letter or number portion you might want to look into the isdigit function at: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm

Comment: A c compiler shouldn't even let you compile with int i and int j defined in the loop conditions. I smell a sneaky c++ compiler being used on a c program here.

Comment: @MPI_What: Defining loop variables in the init part of the `for` is legal (and good) C as of C99.

Comment: For scope, efficiency and cleanliness, I prefer to define variables where they are needed in C++, Java, etc. However, in C I find it easier to simply define them at the top that way no confusion happens if you bounce between compilers. That's just my preference, I should have stated that in the original comment.

Comment: @MOehm Orly? That's something I didn't know. Cheers :).

Answer (score 0):

There are probably 20 ways to do this. The key is to realize you have to increase the number of `'*'`'s by 2 as you reduce the spacing by 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SLIMIT 120

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t height = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) * 2: 12;
    size_t space;
    size_t i;

    if (height < 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid height '%zu'\n", height);
        return 1;
    }

    space = (height + 1)/2;

    for (i = 1; i < height+1; i+=2,space--) {
        char tstring[SLIMIT+1] = {0};
        memset (tstring, '*', i);
        printf ("%*s%s\n", space, " ", tstring);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/triangle 12
            *
           ***
          *****
         *******
        *********
       ***********
      *************
     ***************
    *****************
   *******************
  *********************
 ***********************
```

**Note:** this is currently limited to width of 60 (1/2 `SLIMIT`).